# Which driver I need to use PeakCan in Qt6?

Tags: qt, networking, driver, can-bus

I need to use [Peak System PCAN USB](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html?&L=1) dongle in my Qt6 application.
At first I checked it works from command line.

In my Ubuntu 20.04 I have the kernel drivers installed:

```
$ grep PEAK_ /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCIEFD=m
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCI=m
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCIEC=y
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCMCIA=m
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_USB=m
```

and loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep ^peak
peak_usb               49152  0
```

I also tried to exchange data with `can-tools` and it worked out of the box.
Here the relevant output of the `ip` command:

```
$ ip addr
6: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can
```

The problem arises when I try to connect from the Qt application:

```
std::unique_ptr<QCanBusDevice> _device;
QString errorString;
_device.reset(QCanBus::instance()->createDevice("peakcan", "can0", &errorString));
```

I get:

> qt.canbus.plugins.peakcan: Cannot load library pcanbasic: (pcanbasic: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

So I downloaded the [PCAN Basic](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-Basic.239.0.html?&L=1) package.
In the readme there are the requirements:

```
System Requirements
-------------------
- PCAN Linux Driver: 8.0.17 and above
  (Driver for Linux can be download at www.peak-system.com/linux)
```

So I compiled and installed the drivers. Now the `peakcan` plugin is found:

> qt.canbus.plugins.peakcan: Using PCAN-API version: 4.5.2.15

but now:

- no device is discovered by Qt
- `ip addr` shows no can devices
- `lsmod | grep ^peak` shows no drivers loaded

**Question #1**: am I missing anything in order to get it works?

By the way, in the Linux driver [page](http://www.peak-system.com/linux) they also state:

> The CAN interfaces are then accessed via the common SocketCAN framework as network devices

Hence I tried to find any available device using `socketcan`:

```
QString errorString;
const QList<QCanBusDeviceInfo> devices = QCanBus::instance()->availableDevices(QStringLiteral("socketcan"), &errorString);
if (!errorString.isEmpty()) qDebug() << errorString;
foreach (QCanBusDeviceInfo info, devices)
{
    qDebug() << info.name();
}
```

but it finds no devices.
If I try to connect to it:

```
std::unique_ptr<QCanBusDevice> _device;
QString errorString;
_device.reset(QCanBus::instance()->createDevice("socketcan", "can0", &errorString));
```

I get:

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

I guess because I'm running the application with user privileges.
I get the same error if I try to bring the interface up without `sudo`:

```
$ ip link set can0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

**Question #2**: Is there any group I need to join to in order to let Qt6 to bring up the network device without root privileges?

Comment: I answer to my Question #2: the Qt plugin needs to have the network up. With another `socketcan` device it works, but not with the Peak System one.